# how to lock a field in table for update in sql

Tags: sql-server

Need lock for update a field in a table or maybe pop up a message alter user when this field is update. But still need do be insert or delete a record. i simply try to use command

```
   DENY UPDATE ON JobEmp (Job) TO public
```

It will not let me do any thing to Job Column, can not add, change or delete. Need some help. Thanks 
Using Code

```
   CREATE TRIGGER tr_No_Update_Job
   ON dbo.JobEmp
   FOR UPDATE
   AS
   BEGIN
   IF UPDATE(Job)
    BEGIN
   RAISERROR('This column cannot be updated', 16,1)
   RETURN;
   END
   END
```

But when insert a new record, it also throw the error message. How can i only lock for update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not Grant, Deny or Revok permission on one column of the table you can either deny UPDATE permission on a table on sql server permissions level or you need to create a Trigger to control column level permission.

**Table Level Permissions**

```
DENY UPDATE ON OBJECT::[Schema].[TableName] TO [PrincipalName];
```

**Column Level Update Control**

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_No_Update_Job
ON dbo.JobEmp
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  IF UPDATE(Job)
   BEGIN
       RAISERROR('This column cannot be updated', 16,1)
       RETURN;
   END
END
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and let you know :)

Comment: I did try, however although it through the error message, i still can save any change i make this field.

Answer (score 1):

Do the rollback from after update trigger:

```
create trigger trJobEmpUpd
on JobEmp
after update
as
if update(Job)
  rollback
```

Comment: it is the same, i still can make any change on this field even i receive the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to BEGIN/COMMIT TRAN and transaction isolation levels.

Answer (score 0):

If your questions is about Oracle
There is a syntax "for update" that locks a record (not a field)
[https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4530093713805](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:4530093713805)

-> For SQL server I think the "for update" syntax is "Select ...  WITH (updlock)..."
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026(v=sql.80).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
Note that as been noted by @huMpty duMpty you have to be in a transaction for the lock to be held...

This syntax will issue a row lock on the data selected, which will be released only on commit.
other users will be able to query the data (depends on the DBMS) but not to modify it.

I am pretty sure most other DBMS has the same / similar syntax for locking selected query results, while selecting the data - which allow atomicity - what you got from the "select" will be locked, in the same command, and no one else can intervene in the middle.

---

If you want to permanently not allow access to a column (for select or update) you should use a different scheme, and allow permisions on a view of the data , or only select permission with stored procedures for editing the actualy data.

Comment: Question is tagged with `sql-server` !!

Comment: It was loaded to me only one - was it an update? I searched for the technology before writing.. LOL